# How can I set my VIM color scheme to the same default color scheme in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, color-scheme

Very new to VIM so any explanation on how to configure would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My "Bandit" colour scheme was originally based on the highlighting from Visual Studio (version 6 I think) and Matlab.  It's probably not a perfect match, but it may be of interest.

It's available [here](https://sites.google.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/bandit-colour-scheme) and, in case the screenshot below doesn't work, there's a screenshot [here](https://9079554918504034906-a-1802744773732722657-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/abudden/contents/Vim-Scripts/ctags-highlighting/module_without_ctags_highlighter_light.png?attachauth=ANoY7cryMjb1s-GO9gLrjSLVqeTKkPqDNXH9AdDPDg376RezpKgMqQI2x1ihD0H-fv4PnZP-cXKx21q48V1W1D1n8Dsq4lFOG50pfQXbPkoOQ89d1y8Lu2h0qgHCOWZbMfqkVSgNclu5eb_qQZ0T13ErqqJ2Q8niamUd38d1iTKP7G2pRfEwQdBx_WKLHgjFH4ByOXw6CdDGO6kmvQ6gXryg-kSOnQxj3UEwTKrLdsBOvbE0CIOtkqBeWH-SG9Vwjve2equME0TaX-rFPw0o2v5BX7l5YKwccOqzqzokHIG_ZwfyIp6kwwM%3D&attredirects=0).  Note that you'll need to do:

```
set background=light
```

before configuring the colour scheme as otherwise it will default to a dark background.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Find one [here](http://code.google.com/p/vimcolorschemetest/) that is close to Visual Studio.

Download it and put `colorscheme foo` in your .vimrc (_vimrc on Windows) where `foo` is the name of the colorscheme.

Answer (score 2):

You need to search in the different color schemes. I don't know if there's one who is the same as in Visual Studio, but maybe you'll find a better one. :)

Type a little piece of code, then `:colorscheme`, a space, and press Tab to see every colorscheme.
You can download new colorschemes here : http://www.vim.org/search.php

Answer (score 0):

The "VC" color scheme (found [here](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/colors/vc.vim)) is very close to looking like the default Visual Studio color scheme.